# Does the blessing of Genesis 12:3 extend to Palestine or is it only for Israel (and the church as the spiritual Israel)?

Tags: israel, abraham

I was reading 12:3 and I started to wonder whether or not that blessing was for Palestinians too, as descendants of Abraham. Thank you.

Comment: This is too opinion based to answer for this site. If you have a specific Christian tradition or doctrine set in mind that we could frame the question and answer to, that might work. Another option is to ask for an "overview" of beliefs, but I can say I know enough about this topic if that would work on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Does the blessing of Genesis 12:3 extend to Palestine or is it only for Israel?**

The Bible quite clearly shows the Genesis 12:3 blessing being passed along for several generations, bypassing the ancestors of the Palestinians.

God *did* provide their ancestors with blessings, but *not* the specific blessing of Genesis 12:3, which was the beginning of the old covenant.

---

Modern Palestinians are Arabs, descended from Abraham's son Ishmael ([Ishmaelites - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishmaelites)).

God told Abraham to pass his blessing on to his second son, Isaac, not to his son Ishmael.  God provided a separate blessing for Ishmael:

> And God said, Sarah thy wife shall bear thee a son indeed; and thou shalt call his name **Isaac**: and **I will establish my covenant with him** for an everlasting covenant, **and with his seed** after him.
>
> And as for Ishmael, I have heard thee: Behold, I have blessed him, and will make him fruitful, and will multiply him exceedingly; twelve princes shall he beget, and I will make him a great nation.
>
> — Genesis 17:19,20

The Covenant that God made with Abraham was passed to Isaac, not to Ishmael, and so not to the ancestor nations of today's Palestinians.

Similarly, Isaac passed the blessing on to his son Jacob, not to his eldest son Esau, who had sold his right to the blessing to Jacob:

> And Jacob said, Swear to me this day; and he sware unto him: and he sold his birthright unto Jacob.
>
> — Genesis 25:33

Esau (also known as [Edom - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edom), possibly the ancestor of modern Turks) also received a blessing, but it was a different blessing (Gen 27:38), not part of Abraham's covenant with God.

Later, because of Reuben's transgression, Jacob (Israel) passed the spiritual blessing to his son Judah, and the physical blessing to his son Joseph, rather than to his eldest son Reuben:

> Now the sons of Reuben the firstborn of Israel, (for he was the firstborn; but, forasmuch as he defiled his father's bed, his birthright was given unto the sons of Joseph the son of Israel: and the genealogy is not to be reckoned after the birthright. For **Judah** prevailed above his brethren, and **of him came the chief ruler**; but **the birthright was Joseph's**)
>
> —  1 Chronicles 5:1

Centuries later, when the kingdom split into two, the Jews (Judea, descendants of Judah) retained the spiritual blessing (the Messiah would come from them), while the name "Israel" went with Joseph's sons:

> **The sceptre shall not depart from Judah**, nor a lawgiver from between his feet, until Shiloh come; and unto him shall the gathering of the people be.
> …
> **The blessings** of thy father have prevailed above the blessings of my progenitors unto the utmost bound of the everlasting hills: they **shall be on the head of Joseph**, and on the crown of the head of him that was separate from his brethren.
>
> — Genesis 49:10,26

Comment: This answer is wholly based on the mistaken assumption that modern-day Palestinians descend from Ishmael.  While “Arabs” in Palestine today may identify with Arab ethnicity, the DNA evidence suggests they are indigenous to Palestine, dating back to the Iron Age – their ancestors were Judean.  The OP asks an excellent, unanswerable question: who today are legitimate heirs of the ancient promises?

Comment: @Schuh says "*the DNA evidence suggests they are indigenous to Palestine, dating back to the Iron Age – their ancestors were Judean*" — Are you saying that the modern Palestinians are actually Jewish? What is a reference for the DNA evidence?

Comment: Ray, you can look up the genetic and historiographic studies elsewhere. You’ll find that many Palestinians and many Jewish people descend from the same ancient people group in the land.